# How to execute multiple commands from one script in Linux

Tags: bash, command, vlc

The problem with each command is that it has a continuous output that does not allow me to execute any more commands. Each command can only be stopped by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or killing the session. Executing 1 command per terminal window works but is time consuming and inefficient. This question is in relation to VLC application that outputs video status information until killed. Seeing output from each command is not necessary.

Comment: batch file as in Windows?

Comment: Sorry, Linux. Ubuntu to be more precise.

Comment: `command1 >> /dev/null & command2 >> /dev/null & command3 >> /dev/null & wait`

Comment: was @twalberg said, you can use command redirection `command > /dev/null 2>&1 & `  will put it in the background and dump both stderr and stdout to dev/null

Comment: So basically I just line up all the commands in a script and redirect the output to /dev/null? Sorry cant test now but I assume after I redirect the input I a am back at shell able to execute other commands?

Comment: I still see the output from VLC

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Doon, `&` (to background the process) will do the trick.

However, the process will die if you close the terminal. If you want the backgrounded process not to die if you close the terminal it was started in, you can prefix the process with `nohup`.

Extended from example above:

```
nohup command1 > /dev/null 2>&1 &;
nohup command2 > /dev/null 2>&1 &;
...
```

Comment: So would my command look like this?
nohup ./vlc -I http option option option 'transcode(option)' > /dev/null 2>&1 &;   ?

Comment: Yes that should do it